# Как получить содержимое ссылок?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить содержимое ссылок c BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')? Не сами ссылки а название!
есть вот такой код:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://kyxni.pro/katalog/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='builder-posts-wrap')
for i in soup.find_all('h2', class_='post-title'):
print(i)
```

выводит ссылки:

```
<h2 class="post-title entry-title"><a href="https://kyxni.pro/kuxnya-elegiya/">Кухня ЭЛЕГИЯ</a> </h2>
<h2 class="post-title entry-title"><a href="https://kyxni.pro/kuxnya-diana/">Кухня ДИАНА</a> </h2>
<h2 class="post-title entry-title"><a href="https://kyxni.pro/kuxni-temza/">Кухня ТЕМЗА</a> </h2>
```

а я хочу получить сами названия:

```
Кухня ЭЛЕГИЯ
Кухня ДИАНА
Кухня ТЕМЗА
и т.д.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?

И как можно открыть сохранённую страницу, что бы каждый раз сайт не грузить?
Такая конструкция в коде который выше не работает

```
html = open('kuhni.html').read()
```

Comment: Что есть название?

Comment: `i.text_content()` что ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> а я хочу получить сами названия:

```
for i in soup.find_all('h2', class_='post-title entry-title'):
    print(i.text)
```

Когда нужно получить текстовое содержимое, применяйте атрибут text (только не к списку, который возвращается методом find_all).

> И как можно открыть сохранённую страницу, что бы каждый раз сайт не
>   грузить? Такая конструкция в коде который выше не работает

У меня получилось так:

```
html = open('kuhni.html', encoding='utf8').read()
```

P.S. На будущее. Приводите текст ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
In [210]: [x.text for x in soup.select("h2.post-title a")]
Out[210]:
['Кухня ЭЛЕГИЯ',
 'Кухня ДИАНА',
 'Кухня ТЕМЗА',
 'Кухня ОРХИДЕЯ',
 'Кухня CRYSTAL',
 'Кухня SAFARI',
 'Кухня SCANDIA',
 'Кухня INVERNO',
 'Кухня МЕРАНО',
 'Кухня МОНТЕБЬЯНКО АРГЕНТО',
 'Кухня МОНТЕБЬЯНКО',
 'Кухня ДОЛОМИТА',
 'Кухня ГАРДА',
 'Кухня АСТИ',
 'Кухня КВАТРО ГРАФИТ',
 'Кухня КВАТРО БЕЛЫЙ',
 'Кухня КВАТРО ПЕСОЧНЫЙ',
 'Кухня МАНЧЕСТЕР ФИСТАШКА',
 'Кухня МАНЧЕСТЕР ЛЕН',
 'Кухня МИЛАН БЬЯНКО',
 'Кухня ОКСФОРД БЕЛЫЙ ДУБ',
 'Кухня ОКСФОРД ГРАФИТ',
 'Кухня КАПРИ',
 'Кухня ЭЛЬБА',
 'Кухня КОРТИНА',
 'Кухня ГЕСТИЯ',
 'Кухня ДЕМЕТРА',
 'Кухня АСКОТ',
 'Кухня РИАЛЬТО',
 'Кухня ТРИЕСТЕ',
 'Кухня ВЕНЕЦИЯ',
 'Кухня ФИРЕНЦЕ',
 'Кухня СОРРЕНТО',
 'Кухня ПОЗИТАНО',
 'Кухня ВИКТОРИЯ',
 'Кухня РОМАНТИКА',
 'Кухня НИКА НОЧЕ',
 'Кухня НИКА',
 'Кухня НИКА Д’ОРО БЕЛАЯ',
 'Кухня НИКА Д’ОРО БЕЖЕВАЯ',
 'Кухня АФИНА АРГЕНТО',
 'Кухня АФИНА ОРО',
 'Кухня ТУРИН',
 'Кухня ПРОВАНС ПРАЙМЕР',
 'Кухня ПРОВАНС',
 'Кухня ПОРТОФИНО КАПУЧИНО',
 'Кухня ПОРТОФИНО БЕЛАЯ',
 'Кухня АМАЛЬФИ СЕРАЯ',
 'Кухня АМАЛЬФИ БЕЖЕВАЯ',
 'Кухня РОЗА ДЕКАПЕ',
 'Кухня РОЗА',
 'Кухня ЛУКРЕЦИЯ ЗОЛОТАЯ',
 'Кухня КОРИ',
 'Кухня ЛУКРЕЦИЯ',
 'Кухня ВЕРОНА']
```