# Как в python 3, с помощью BeautifulSoup и find, получить анкор ссылки?

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Подскажите,
с помощью BeautifulSoup парсю страницу и забираю нужные теги по классу:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
list = soup.findAll("a", class_="1NPSa")
print(list)

[<a class="1NPSa" href="/ru/catalogue/acer/models/80/"> 3 </a>, <a class="1NPSa" href="/ru/catalogue/acer/models/0/"> 1 </a>]
```

я знаю, как получить href ссылки:
list[0].find('a').get('href')

А как получить анкор ссылки?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ тут 
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768993/Как-получить-содержимое-ссылок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768993/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Решение:

```
list = [<a class="1NPSa" href="/models/80/"> 3 </a>, <a class="1NPSa" href="/models/0/"> 1 </a>]
print(list[0].text)
>> 3
```